# Updating an instance with changed value object in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to separate domain specific code from underlying ORM bindings, as follows:

```js
class User {
    doDomainSpecificLogic() {
        // some code that changes user instance
    }
}

const userInstance = await userModel.findOne(...);
const user = Object.setPrototypeOf(userInstance.get(), User);

user.doDomainSpecificLogic();

await userInstance.update(user); // UPDATE is not called!
```

However this does not work, presumably because Sequelize considers the `user` object as having not changed, since `update()` gets what was returned by `get()`, i.e. the same (as Sequelize assumes) `dataValues` object.

My current workaround is to detach `userInstance` from `user` by creating another model instance:

```js
await userModel.build(user, { isNewRecord: false }).save();
```

Is there any way to stick with only one model instance?